# How to log errors in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: error

I am new to working with ExpressionEngine, so this may be an easy answer. I am getting 500 errors and can't seem to find any ExpressionEngine log files. How can I log errors in ExpressionEngine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi @Andrew error 500s are server errors. To my knowledge EE does not log such errors. You would need to request/access the logs from your host provider. Here's [some info](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/where-can-i-find-the-logs) on where to access the logs if you're hosting locally using MAMP.

The specific server logs you'd want to look at would be the Apache logs, Access and Error which can ofter be located in the (/var/log/httpd/access or /var/log/httpd/error) directories. You may also want to check /var/log/messages as well.

A common reason for 500 errors is the PHP memory_limit set too low. Here's how [you might fix that](http://www.darian-brown.com/increase-php-memory-limit-in-htaccess-apache-or-in-a-php-script/).

Another idea might be to run the [server wizard](http://ellislab.com/asset/file/ee_server_wizard.zip) to rule out any incompatibilities there.

Finally, if only parts of the site are throwing 500s you might want to try [turning on debugging](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html). You can do so in the CP under Admin -> System Administration - > Output and debugging or manually by adding the following to your system/expressionengine/config/config.php file:

$config['debug'] = "1";

Comment: Thanks for the resources. Yes, a 5xx error is a server-side error which could be an application error. I was hoping EE had its own log file separate from the Apache logs. The error was only occurring yesterday in the admin area when saving a channel entry. Now I can't get the error to reoccur.

Comment: PHP logs would help you out. You can set `error_reporting` to something useful, `display_errors` to off and with `error_log` set log errors that might happen before EE could have even reported them to a file. These all need to happen in your php.ini (or conf.d custom configuration) in order to properly catch some errors). Be sure to check your index.php for both admin and frontend though as it often overrides these settings.